# Error in mysqli_close in php

Tags: php

I've done something stupid T_T

I was rewrite scripts for making pagination in my code, I've tried to make all the scripts that I was googled to make it works. But accidentally I overwrite the original scripts and save it. Actually I've already rename the files for my backup but I was paste the scripts that I get from some tutorials into the wrong windows on my php-editor. Sucks and I was stupid exactly. Now I have troubles with this scripts, I've tried everything, take examples scripts from this forums too, but no results. The errors are: (it works before I was overwrites the connection code)

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\acikiwir\index.php on line 8

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\acikiwir\index.php on line 19

Title | Author | Publisher | Category | Link
```

My scripts:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_books");

$query = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT b.*, title, author_name, url_flipbook, p.publisher_name,    ct.cat_name FROM flipbook AS b
                       LEFT JOIN mst_publisherflip AS p ON b.publisher_id=p.publisher_id
                       LEFT JOIN mst_catflip AS ct ON b.cat_id=ct.cat_id
                       ORDER BY flip_id');
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Author</th>
<th>Publisher</th>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Link</th>
</tr>";

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['author_name'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['publisher_name'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['cat_name'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['url_flipbook'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      }
    echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

In that scripts I only changes the connection code, the original was deleted/overwrites with some's include code so I have to make the connection file again separated from this main scripts. I've tried to wrote the code connection from this forums, but still get errors. Thank you so much if you guys can help me with this problems..thank you..thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running `mysqli_query` twice. That is the main issue.

Rewrite like this..

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT b.*, title, author_name, url_flipbook, p.publisher_name,    ct.cat_name FROM flipbook AS b
                       LEFT JOIN mst_publisherflip AS p ON b.publisher_id=p.publisher_id
                       LEFT JOIN mst_catflip AS ct ON b.cat_id=ct.cat_id
                       ORDER BY flip_id') or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you...you help me a lot and save my day...it's 01.30 am here T_T you save me...thank you @Shankar Damodaran, best regards...